# What cache service should I use?

Tags: 9, caching

I just used a cache service explicitely for the first time, in a function that calls a remote service. The result is a simple string that may change day by day, but it's very rare that it changes for the past – so I expire it at midnight.

I injected `cache.default` in my controller – then I saw that in core services there is also a service called `cache.data`. What's the difference? Is there any reason to prefer one to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ### Cache bins
>
> Cache storage is separated into "bins", each containing
> various cache items. Each bin can be configured separately; see
> Configuration.
>
> When you request a cache object, you can specify the bin name in your
> call to \Drupal::cache(). Alternatively, you can request a bin by
> getting service "cache.nameofbin" from the container. The default bin
> is called **default**, with service name `cache.default`, it is used
> to store common and frequently used caches.
>
> Other common cache bins are the following:
>
> - **bootstrap:** Data needed from the beginning to the end of most requests, that has a very strict limit on variations and is
>   invalidated rarely.
> - **render:** Contains cached HTML strings like cached pages and blocks, can grow to large size.
> - **data:** Contains data that can vary by path or similar context.
> - **discovery:** Contains cached discovery data for things such as plugins, views_data, or YAML discovered data such as library info.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/cache

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had missed that – Drupal documentation can be overwhelming, sometimes :/

Comment: And it seems that `cache.default` is the right choice, after all :)

Comment: One thing to notice is the `DEFAULT_MAX_ROWS` constant value and the configurable setting for the `DatabaseBackend` class that currently defaults to 5000.
This could be import as `garbageCollection` method would delete the oldest entries that exceed that limitation. Due to this fact, it might make sense to create a custom cache bin to make sure that the cache is not seemingly _randomly_ deleted.